# Google sign in - enable server side access ios redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: ios, google-oauth, google-identity

I have integrated the google ios SDK for a signIn in my app and able to generate the authorization code using the same. While trying to use the same authorization code on the server-side, I keep getting the redirect_uri_mismatch error. There is not any redirect URI set in google API console for Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in).

[Here is my credentials details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M4TR.png)

I have downloaded the same credential JSON and using it with the Python code provided in the [google doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using the provided python example, I used custom OAuth client and passing ```redirect_uri : ""``` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect UI is important for web applications in order to know where to redirect after login is completed. Add one which is applicable in your case or you can add base url of your website for it work in case you are just adding google sign-in in your app and not on web.